# Dynamic Record Ids in Embedded Visualforce page within Lightning Record Page

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, standardcontroller, dynamic-apex, lightning-record-page

We are working on an AppExchange app, where we need to embed the below widget code into Salesforce lightning record page.

```
<!--- EmbedWidget Visualforce Page -->
<apex:page  controller="EmbedWidgetCtrl"  > <!-- StandardController is not added to make page dynamic -->
 <form style="width: 13rem ; " class="m-2 col-6" id="theExternalForm" method="POST" onsubmit="onSubmit()"  action="https://abc.xyz.com/externalFormPost"   >

    <input type="hidden" name="CurrentRecordId" value="{!currentRecordId}"/>   
    <input  type="hidden"   name="UserToken" value="{!UserToken}"/> 
    <br/> {!currentRecordId}  </form>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("theExternalForm").submit(); 
    </script>
</apex:page>

<!--- EmbedWidget Visualforce Page Controller -->
public with sharing class EmbedWidgetCtrl{
 
public String currentRecordId {get;set;}
public String UserToken{get;set;}
 public EmbedWidgetCtrl()
 { 
     currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
     UserToken = 'Some code to generate token';
 }
}
```

**Question:**
We need to pass the dynamic SF record ID to the external widget. For which we are using below code in apex class of Visualforce page.

```
 currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
```

Above code is returning us the dynamic record IDs of different objects (e.g. Account, Contact or custom objects) using the above code.  It looks like when we embed a VFP in Lightning Page Builder (record page), it automatically passes an ID parameter as we get in the StandardController/hasRecordId interface.

We couldn't find any documentation around this behaviour for Visualforce page, can someone please confirm, **is it okay to build the solution based on the POC that we will always get an ID parameter in a VFP, when it's included in a Lighting Record page? Or if there is any documentation around this behaviour kindly share.**